# How can I install PyQT4 for Python 2.7?

Tags: python, macos, qt, python-2.7, pyqt

I am trying to install PyQT4 on Python 2.7.9, I am on Mac OS X, so i tried installing it via Homebrew and Macports, unfortunately non of them seemed to work.

This is what I tried:

```
brew install python qt pyqt pyside pyside-tools
```

also tried:

```
brew install PyQT4
```

On Macports:

```
sudo port install py27-pyqt4
```

No matter what I did, I was getting this error:

```
>>>> import PyQT4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQT4
```

What can be the problem? Do I need to set env path for PyQT?

Comment: It's not called `PyQT4`. It's called `PyQt4` (notice the lowercase t)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Found out solution:

I installed PyQtX package, (PyQt binary for Mac OS X) from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqtx/).

and then specified `PYTHONPATH` with this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

After typing in `import PyQt4` it worked without any problems. (Case Sensitive)

Comment: If you don't want to perform the export, you can do the following prior to importing PyQt4: `import sys; sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')`

Comment: On my Mac El Capitan 10.11.6 running the PyQt4 installer reported "Python 2.7 from official python website is not installed." and failed to continue.

Comment: @MarcelStör make sure you have installed python 2.7 from it's installer (It would be best way to install python ), but before doing that, delete the old directory: `rm -rif /usr/local/lib/python2.7/`

Comment: ATM I'm lost among the various Python installation options (Apple, official, MacPorts, Homebrew). Trying to revert to clean-sheet installation.

Comment: @MarcelStör i would recommend downloading it's `.pkg` installer from official website.

Comment: Installed Python 2.7. Worked to launch PyQt4

Comment: Started installing PyQt4 ... (may corrupt system. failed.)
I don't know how it works for others but it is not a solution at all ._.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me:
https://robonobodojo.wordpress.com/2017/02/08/installing-pyqt4-on-mac-osx/

What did it was `brew install cartr/qt4/pyqt`