# No module named PyQt4 although it is installed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

**I want to run FlatCAM on MAC OS X El Capitan and it needs PyQt package. I installed PyQt4 using homebrew.**

```
brew install qt
```

Warning: qt-4.8.7_2 already installed

```
brew install pyqt
```

Warning: pyqt-4.11.4 already installed

```
brew install sip
```

Warning: sip-4.18.1 already installed

```
brew install PyQt --with-python
```

Warning: pyqt-4.11.4 already installed

**Although these warnings, when I run FlatCAM, I take this error:**

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "FlatCAM.py", line 2, in 
from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: No module named PyQt4*

**Why it doesn't see PyQt4?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlatCAM uses python 2.7 but default homebrew installation seems like using python3.

Solution here: [How can i install PyQT4 for Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615952/how-can-i-install-pyqt4-for-python-2-7)

Comment: It seems it's not anymore..