# How do install python-qt4 on my vitual environment on mac using pip or brew

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip, homebrew

I want to install **python-Qt4** library on my virtual environment on mac. I am running python 2.7. It's recommended to use:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
```

for mac and linux users but this fails for me since mac has no `apt-get` command . So I tried using `brew install python-qt4` but I get this error message:

```
Updating Homebrew...
Error: No available formula with the name "python-qt4" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula... Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae... Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps... Error: No formulae found in taps
```

I tried running `pip install python-qt4` but I also get this error message:

```
Collecting python-qt4   Could not find a version that satisfies the
requirement python-qt4 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for python-qt4
```

I have tried all the solutions in [How can i install PyQT4 for Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615952/how-can-i-install-pyqt4-for-python-2-7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i install PyQT4 for Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615952/how-can-i-install-pyqt4-for-python-2-7)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i tried that but it did not workout for me

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, thanks for re-echoing that, i followed it once again and it helped though i had to reinstall python2.7 from its installer before it cud work

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
brew install cartr/qt4/pyq
```